# $F$ is algebraically closed in $F(X)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let $F$ be a field and $q \in F(X)\setminus F$. Show the following:

**1)** Two coprime polynomials $f, g \in F[X]$ exist, so that $q=f/g$.

**2)** The polynomial
$$a(T):=f(T)-g(T)q \in F(q)[T]$$ is the minimal polynomial of $X$ over $F(q)$. This also shows $$[F(X):F(q)]=\max[\deg(f),\deg(g)].$$

**3)** $F$ is algebraically closed in $F(X)$.

So I've already shown that $a(T)$ is irreducible, but I still have to show that $a(X)=0$. This doesn't seem too hard, but how am I supposed to do that without knowing $f,g$? Since $[F(X):F(q)]$ is defined as the degree of the minimal polynomial of $X$ with coefficients in $F(q)$ and $a(T)$ is the sum of two polynomials, its degree must be the $\max[\deg(f),\deg(g)]$, right?

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: For 3), I think we actually say "purely transcendental"…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1 follows directly from the definition of $F(X)$ and the fact that $F[X]$ is a PID, so one can express
$$
q=\frac{f_0}{g_0}=\frac{f}{g}
$$
where $f=f_0/\gcd(f_0,g_0)$ and $g=g_0/\gcd(f_0,g_0)$.

If you have already proved that $a(T)$ is irreducible, then you're done:
$$
a(X)=f(X)-g(X)\frac{f(X)}{g(X)}=0
$$
The degree of $a(T)$ is clearly $\max\{\deg f(T),\deg g(T)\}$.

Part 3 is nothing more than showing that, if $q\in F(X)$ is algebraic over $F$, then $q\in F$. Note that, if $q\in F(X)$ is algebraic over $F$, then $[F(q):F]$ is finite. If $q\notin F$, then also $[F(X):F(q)]$ is finite. Then…

Comment: Then $q$ is transcendental over $F$, which cannot be, because otherwise $[F(q):F]$ would be infinite?

Comment: @Yasuduck Almost: You'd get that $[F(X):F]$ is finite.

Comment: But why wouldn't it suffice to use my argument?

Comment: @Yasuduck If $q$ is algebraic over $F$, then $[F(q):F]$ is finite. You have to use what you proved before.

Comment: I think I got it now, thanks for your help.